# www prefix is not working locally

Tags: networking, router, dns, nas, synology

Hi i recently put a web page online on a synology NAS, the problem is the following:

**When typing www. before my domain name the page is not loading**

This is what i got so far:

- Added both example.com and www.example.com to the synology Virtual Hosts
- Check the CNAME configuration on GoDaddy - www subdomain is added
- Port forwarding - Added HTTP server entry linked to my NAS
- Flush computer dns cache with the ipconfig /flushdns
- Read dns cache with the ipconfig /displaydns
- Resetting the modem
- Change DNS primary and secondary modem servers to google servers (8.8.8.8)

The problem is on my modem because when i make a ping on my local network to "mydomain.com" its ip is diferent from "www.mydomain.com" ip, but when i make a ping connected to another network (shared internet from my cellphone), both pings succeed

The port forwarding is ok because if I enter http://example.com or my public ip on the browser the page is loaded

I checked with other computers and the problem is the same, but only when connected using my modem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be your modem/router is not doing port forwarding if the traffic is coming from internal interface. Some routers handle it out of the box, some need additional configuration, some cannot do it at all.

**Solution 1:**

Research how to configure your modem/router to also handle port forwarding for internal traffic.

**Solution 2:**

Configure internal DNS for your internal network. Setup mydomain.com with it.

PS: Without complete information on the internal network setup(hosts file, dns entries on each device, etc), it is difficult to determine how your domain works correctly without www.